# Error within tidy text. unnest_tokens was deprecated

Tags: r, tidytext

`unnest_tokens()` was deprecated in tidytext 0.4.0 and is now defunct

Attempting to create a 2-node graph through twitter data within R and am receiving the following error message.

```
twomode_network <- twitter_data %>% Create("twomode", removeTermsOrHashtags = c("#auspol"), verbose = TRUE)
twomode_graph <- twomode_network %>% Graph()

Generating twitter 2-mode network...
Error:
! `unnest_tokens()` was deprecated in tidytext 0.4.0 and is now defunct.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this! I fixed this (confusing) message [on GitHub here](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/commit/12073e26a6f6be9d522982006f747455d1ea2fe6) and now you correctly see this:

```r
library(tidytext)

d <- tibble::tibble(
  txt = c("Because I could not stop for Death -", "He kindly stopped for me -"),
  line = 1:2
)

d |> unnest_tweets(word, txt)
#> Error:
#> ! `unnest_tweets()` was deprecated in tidytext 0.4.0 and is now defunct.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As before you will see this error when using `unnest_tokens()` with `token = "tweets"`:

```r
library(tidytext)

d <- tibble::tibble(
  txt = c("Because I could not stop for Death -", "He kindly stopped for me -"),
  line = 1:2
)

d |> unnest_tokens(word, txt, token = "tweets")
#> Error:
#> ! Support for `token = "tweets"` was deprecated in tidytext 0.4.0 and is
#>   now defunct.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The tweet-specific tokenizer was removed because of changes in upstream dependencies; you can see this [in the documentation here](https://juliasilge.github.io/tidytext/reference/unnest_tokens.html#details-1).